# Status bar remains in landscape mode when using camera android

Tags: android, camera, statusbar, landscape-portrait

So after a while of messing with the camera, I've finally got the actual camera orientation working with this:

```
private void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
                                         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

However, the status bar (the thing at the top with time and network info) is still in landscape. 
I've already included this:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please post the full **activity** tag of your app manifest

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you want to set your orientation as you can use `setRequestedOrientation(int requestedOrientation)` in your `Activity`

Comment: This causes my screen to go back and the log to output "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question. I don't believe you can have the the status bar in portrait if your camera is in landscape, since you're setting the orientation with `camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);` why not just have a full screen camera preview so you don't have to worry about the status bar. As for your log giving you that output, you should move any long processes off the `UI` thread